# How do I solve this sql syntax error? near (pl.name, ' ', CASE WHEN pal.name is not null THEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pal.nam'

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

Apparently,I have a syntax error that I don't get, could you help me?

```
SELECT p.id_product, pa.ean13,pa.upc,p.active, p.isBike, p.isDirect, p.weight,p.height, p.width, p.depth, pa.reference, pl.description_short, pa.upc, p.price, pai.id_image CONCAT(pl.name, \' \', CASE WHEN pal.name is not null THEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pal.name) SEPARATOR ", ") ELSE "" END) as name
        FROM ps_product p
        LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)﻿
        LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute pa ON (p.id_product = pa.id_product)
        LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON (pac.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute)﻿
        LEFT JOIN ps_attribute_lang pal ON (pal.id_attribute = pac.id_attribute)
        LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available s ON (p.id_product = s.id_product)
        WHERE pl.id_lang = 1
        AND p.id_shop_default = 1
        AND pl.name LIKE "%PRODUCT NAME%"
        GROUP BY pac.id_product_attribute
        ORDER BY pl.name﻿
        LIMIT 60﻿﻿﻿﻿'
```

Comment: add comma after `pai.id_image`

Comment: `pai.id_image` comma missing

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I apparently have another syntax error near
EFT JOIN ps_product_attribute pa ON (p.id_product = pa.id_product)
            LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON (pac.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute)

Comment: Maybe `CONCAT(pl.name, " "` instead of `CONCAT(pl.name, \' \'`?

Answer (score 0):

Besides a missing comma in the SELECT statement, you were also missing a LEFT JOIN on the ps_product_attribute_image table, here's the correct SQL query:

```
SELECT p.id_product, pa.ean13, pa.upc, p.active, p.isBike, p.isDirect, p.weight, p.height, p.width, p.depth, pa.reference, pl.description_short, pa.upc, p.price, pai.id_image,
CONCAT(pl.name, ' ', CASE WHEN pal.name is not null THEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pal.name) SEPARATOR ', ') ELSE '' END) as name
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute pa ON (p.id_product = pa.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON (pac.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute)
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_image pai ON (pai.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute)
LEFT JOIN ps_attribute_lang pal ON (pal.id_attribute = pac.id_attribute)
LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available s ON (p.id_product = s.id_product)
WHERE pl.id_lang = 1
AND p.id_shop_default = 1
AND pl.name LIKE '%PRODUCT NAME%'
GROUP BY pac.id_product_attribute
ORDER BY pl.name
LIMIT 60
```